# Selenium Java Keep refreshing page until element visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium Java Keep refreshing page until element visible.

I need Page to keep refreshing until element is visible.

```
do{
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    //DEV
}while(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='UserID']")).isDisplayed());
```

This code refresh only one time. I need to keep refresh (10 times or more) until element is visible.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working as intended? Is there maybe another element that matches that locator? I don't see anything wrong with that code. I would add a counter and fail the test at some point... what if the element never appears because of a bug, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The `findElement()` throws an exception if the element is not present - thus the loop spins once, the exception is thrown, and the loop stops. So you need to handle that:

```
boolean displayed = false;
do{
  try{
    displayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='UserID']")).isDisplayed());
  } catch (NoSuchElementException){
    driver.navigate().refresh();
  }
} while(!displayed);
```

It won't hurt if you add some counter/max timer logic, otherwise if the element doesn't appear, the loop will spin endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of the element by picking it up using `List<WebElement>` and then refresh the page till the size of the list becomes greater than 0 (as the size of the list of that element will become greater than 0 when it displays on the UI).

Code for the above logic can be like this:

```
    int refreshCount = 10;    
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[text()='UserID']"));    
    for (int i = 0; i < refreshCount; i++) {    
        if (element.size() > 0) {     
            // Do the operation here on the element    
        } else {    
            driver.navigate().refresh();    
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findElements instead of findElement or you can handle exception && implement a counter for sanity as mentioned by @Todor.

`findElements()` will return an empty list if no matching elements are found instead of an exception.

```
do {
//xyz
} while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='UserID']")).isEmpty())
```

This will return true if at least one element is found and false if it does not exist.

From the docs,

> Each of the language bindings exposes a “Find Element” and “Find
>   Elements” method. The former returns a WebElement object matching the
>   query, and **throws an exception** if such an element cannot be found. The
>   latter returns a list of WebElements, possibly empty if no DOM
>   elements match the query.